# Fetch data via search from two Table with where condition in Laravel ,vuejs

Tags: javascript, mysql, laravel, vue.js, eloquent

I want to fetch data  from two tables Employee and Company via search by  typing Company name not by company Id the tables are linked with one to many Relationship.they rest search functionality is working perfect.any help would be highly appreciated.

**Code in EmployeeController is :**

```
 public function search(){

       if($search = \Request::get('q')){

             $employees = Employee::where(function($query) use ($search){
                 $companies = Company::Where('id','company_id');
                $searcompany ?????
                foreach($companies AS $company){ 
                     $searcompany = $company->Company;
                }

                $query->Where('BadgeCode','LIKE',"%$search%")              
                 ->orWhere($searcompany,'LIKE',"%$search%")

            })->orderBy('BadgeCode','desc')->paginate(20);
                            // return $users;
        }        else{
           $employees = Employee::latest()->paginate(5);
                     }
         return $employees;

    }
```

**HTML Code in Employee.vue is :**

```
<div style="margin-left:450px; margin-top:0px;margin-bottom:-10px;">
              <h3 class="card-title">
                <div class="card-tools">
                  <div class="input-group input-group-sm" style="width: 250px;">
                    <input
                      name="table_search"
                      class="form-control float-right"
                      placeholder="Search"
                      @keyup="searchit"
                      v-model="search"
                      type="search"
                      aria-label="Search"
                    />
                    <div class="input-group-append">
                      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" @click="searchit">
                        <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
                      </button>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </h3>
            </div>
```

**Script Code in Employee.vue is :**

```
    export default {
    data() {
        return {
employees :{},
     search: "",
    },
        methods: {
            searchit: _.debounce(() => {
              Fire.$emit("searching");
            }, 300),
    },

    created() {
        Fire.$on("searching", () => {
          let query = this.search;
          axios
            .get("api/findemployee?q=" + query)
            .then(data => {
              this.employees = data.data;
            })

            .catch(() => {});
        });
    }
    }
```

**API Rout is :**

```
Route::get('findemployee','API\EmployeeController@search');
```

Answer (score 0):

Controller method looks like overenginired.
You should do something like this.

```
$employees = Employee::with('Company')
    ->when($request->filled('q'), function ($query) use ($request) {
        return $query
           ->where('name', 'like', "%$request->q%")
           ->whereHas('Company', function ($query)  use ($request) {
                return $query->where('name', 'like', "%$request->q%");
            });
    })->paginate(5);
```

put your field name.

Comment: it shows in console     "message": "Call to a member function filled() on string",   my company table name is companies which have id and Company column

Comment: Thet's coz you didn't get Request as argument of method.